# how to properly dynamically add a checkbox and position it with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, dynamically-generated

I am trying to use jquery to:

1- dynamically add a checkbox 
 2- position it correctly.

So far I can do 1 or 2 but not 1 and 2.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<body>   
 <div id='myDiv'></div>
 <div id='myOtherDiv'>
 <button id='myButton'>my button</button>
 </div> 
</body>
```

and here is my js code:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
jQuery(document).ready(

function ($)
{
  jQuery.noConflict();

function createCheckbox()
{
var   $myCheckbox   = $('<input id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox"></input><label for="myCheckbox">my checkbox</label>');
 $('#myDiv').append($myCheckbox);

 /*                                                                                                                                                          
  The following line fixes the "button displayed as unpressed" problem                                                                          
  but it breaks the .position call                                                                                                                           
 */
 // $myCheckbox = $('#myDiv > input');                                                                                                                       

    /* myCheckbox */
   $myCheckbox.button({
                      text: false,
                      icons: { primary: "ui-icon-refresh"}
      });

  $myCheckbox.change(
      function()
              {
                  if($myCheckbox.is(":checked"))
                  { alert('checked'); }
        else
                  {   alert('unchecked');}
              }
    );

var $myButton = $('#myButton');
$myCheckbox.position({my:"left", at:"right", of:$myButton });
}

createCheckbox();

});
```

The code above works but after clicking on the checkbox and clicking "OK" on the "checked" alert, the jquery checkbox button is displayed as unchecked even though the actual checkbox is checked.

By trial and error I fixed that problem by reselecting my checkbox after append. I am not sure why that works though.

```
$myCheckbox = $('#myDiv > input');
```

When I uncommenting the line above, then the checkbox behaves properly and is displayed as checked when it is checked. But then the call to .position does not position the checkbox button properly.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/roumbaba/uM3sS/1/

note: This problems only occurs when i dynamically add an input/checkbox. If I only add a simple button (using a plain  instead of  then both position and checked display satus work fine.

I am clearly missing something major here in how the whole process works. In particular I do not understand why reselecting my checkbox with the  line

```
 $myCheckbox = $('#myDiv > input');
```

changes the behavior of the check status button. And why does position not work after I do that.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use CSS to position it properly?

Comment: I think you're expecting [jQuery `.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) to do something it's not supposed to do.  Doesn't it only _get_ the current position?  http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that i am also using jqueryUI. Position seem to get arguments and it works fine: http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position problem was that I used .position on the checkbox but should have used it on the checkbox's label instead. Apparently jqueryui uses the checkbox's label and not the checkbox itself to display it's button.

```
<!-- language: lang-js --> 
var $myCheckboxLabel = $("label[for='myCheckbox']");
$myCheckboxLabel.position({my:"left", at:"right", of:$myButton });
```

this fixes the position problem while still keeping the checkbox status properly working.

I am still unclear as to why I have to first append my checkbox to the dom and then select it again in order to have a properly functioning checkbox/button after calling .button though.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments. `.position` **does not accept any arguments**.

I have found the following method more reliable and **readable**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('checkbox').live('change', function() {
    if($('#myCheckbox').is(":checked"))
      { alert('checked'); }
    else
      { alert('unchecked'); }
  });
  createCheckbox();
}

function createCheckbox() {
  $('<input/>', {
    id: 'myCheckbox',
    type: 'Checkbox'
  }).appendTo('#myDiv');

  $('<label/>', {
    for: 'myCheckbox',
    text: 'my checkbox'
  }).appendTo('myCheckbox');

  $('<button/>', {
    text: false, // Necessary?
    icons: { primary: "ui-icon-refresh" }
  }.appendTo('myCheckbox');
}
```

Hopefully I have properly understood what you are trying to do. As others have mentioned I would definitely use CSS for proper positioning, not jQuery. It should be fairly straightforward to place `myDiv` to the right of `myOtherDiv`. Just switch their order and use `float: left`.

Comment: Thanks for these alternative methods. I have tried them and I get the exact same behavior than with my original code. .position takes arguments ( i forgot to mention that i am using query UI) api.jqueryui.com/position