# jQuery dynamic checkbox position, merging examples found

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, position, client-side

When dynamically adding checkboxes in jquery, the position is incorrect:
[image]

I have an example (taken from stakoverflow) in JSFiddle of adding checkboxes [dynamically](http://jsfiddle.net/NrwGg/18/).

I also have a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539349/how-to-properly-dynamically-add-a-checkbox-and-position-it-with-jquery) which claims they got it right to add the position,

```
<!-- language: lang-js --> 
var $myCheckboxLabel = $("label[for='myCheckbox']");
$myCheckboxLabel.position({my:"left", at:"right", of:$myButton });
```

but this does not tie up at all with the example as mentioned:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    $("fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" name="' + name + '" id="id' + i + '"><label for="id' + i + '">' + name + ' ' + i + '</label>');
}
```

Can someone please help met to set the position of the checkbox that gets added in the loop, so it does not show next to each other, but in the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript is fine for what you're trying to do - it'll generate the correct HTML. The problem is that they're being displayed "inline" which means that they all go side-by-side, as many on one line as it can fit, then it'll wrap down a line.

What you want is for them to be displayed as a "block" element which means it has its own line, and the next element will have to go underneath it. You can just use CSS to make them do this:

```
fieldset input[type=checkbox] { /* this can be more specific if you need it to be */
    display: block;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrwGg/19/) demo'ing this.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I was able to replicate it, is there a way to get the label to the right of the block please? its currently checkbox and in the next line only the label

Comment: Change the markup you're appending to `<label...><input .../></label>` then set the `display:block;` on the `label` instead

Comment: Any advice on this line please: $("fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" name="' + name + '" id="id' + i + '"><label style="display:block;" for="id' + i + '">' + name + ' ' + i + '</label>');

Comment: Yes, just change the string around so it builds the HTML in the format I described above. Short of writing it for you, I can't get any more specific and clear ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning HTML still, and its gonna take a while to figure it out, but thanks for the headway

Comment: Okie doke, no worries - it's worth doing it yourself because you'll learn more than me just saying "here, paste this". You know where the problem is and what you're shooting for, so you should be fine :-)

Comment: One last question please, is this the method youre referring to ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539349/how-to-properly-dynamically-add-a-checkbox-and-position-it-with-jquery

Comment: I don't quite follow you. Your code is all fine, except the string you're passing into `.append( ...this... )` - you just need to move that around so instead of being `<input /><label>...</label>` it's actually `<label><input />...</label>`